# How to make GrabCut work faster in android?

Tags: android, performance, opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv in android. Grabcut algorithm takes lot of time to remove the background for high resolution images. Is there any way I can reduce the time? Please suggest

Comment: Work on smaller images

Comment: Image clarity decreases.

Comment: If you're okay with a loss of segmentation accuracy you could create a downsampled version of your image, create a mask of that size and apply the smaller mask to the full-sized image. Your final image will still have the same quality and Grabcut will run faster but the segmentation might become a bit blocky.

Comment: @PropaneAccessories - that should be an answer - works great.